# html display property cant change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script works fine for #myLinks but it's not working properly for #myLinks2.

The only thing working for #myLinks2 is the picture change
style

```js
function opentest(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById(x);
  if (y.style.display === "block") {
    if (x == 'myLinks') {
      document.getElementById('citypart').src = "pic/plus.png";
    }
    if (x == 'myLinks2') {
      document.getElementById('roadpart').src = "pic/plus.png";
    }
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    if (x == 'myLinks') {
      document.getElementById('citypart').src = "pic/minus.png";
    }
    if (x == 'myLinks2') {
      document.getElementById('roadpart').src = "pic/minus.png";
    }
    y.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myLinks {
  display: none;
}

#myLinks2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="opentest('myLinks')" style="background-color:#ccc;color: white;">
  <img id="citypart" src="pic/plus.png" height="42" width="42"> travel to
</a>
<div id="myLinks">
  <a href="athen.php">----Athen</a>
</div>
<a onclick="opentest('myLinks2')" style="background-color:#ccc;color: white;">
  <img id="roadpart" src="pic/plus.png" height="42" width="42"> tour type
</a>
<div id="myLinks2">
  <a href="city.php">----Per city</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know but try to use 'else' maybe? If else inside if mylinks == bla bla bla, else mylinks2 == bla bla bla

Answer (score 2):

Delegate and use classes

I moved the links to not have them move around when the div opens

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  const parent = tgt.closest("a");
  if (tgt.tagName === "IMG" && parent && parent.classList.contains("toggle")) tgt = parent;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("toggle")) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop link
    tgt.classList.toggle("open");
    const open = tgt.classList.contains("open")
    tgt.querySelector("img").src = open ? "https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/2x/minus.png" : "https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/2x/plus.png";
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.id).classList.toggle("hide", !open);
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="toggle" href="#" data-id="myLinks">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/2x/plus.png" height="42" width="42"> travel to
  </a>
  <a class="toggle" href="#" data-id="myLinks2">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/2x/plus.png" height="42" width="42"> tour type
  </a>

  <div id="myLinks" class="hide">
    <a href="athen.php">----Athens</a>
  </div>
  <div id="myLinks2" class="hide">
    <a href="city.php">----Per city</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. But the same problem occurs here, too. For #myLink2 only the picture change is working

Comment: No. In this snippet the image changes and "Athen" shows on link1 and "per city" shows on link 2